# Which is faster: my_bool=true; or if(!my_bool)?

Tags: c++

The code below is expected to be **executed many times**

```
m_bool = true; //member variable
```

And `m_bool` will always remain `true` once the above code is executed.

If the following code was used instead, would it be more efficient, in terms of execution time?

```
if (!m_bool)
  m_bool = true;
```

Comment: If you are really concerned about this, look at the generated assembly code. If it is different, profile both versions.

Comment: A fetch-and-test-and-conditional-jump is almost certainly going to be slower than a set.  Have you done any benchmarking?  Is this even the bottleneck?  (Hint: probably not.)

Comment: I would think an `if` would always be faster than an assignment if no change is required, but this could depend on the language and compiler. Are the majority of your use cases needing to make the assignment, or are they superfluous and just doing an extra check?

Comment: If you can't decide it by yourself, why don't you benchmark it? BTW, premature optimization is the root of all evil, profile first!

Comment: I guess this is just another *small* concern, like those one have when comes up the fact that `++i` is faster than `i++` non optimized, or `(_ ? _: _)` is faster than `if _ {} else {}`, while dealing with CUDA. I agree the assignment would be slower, as others said, if considering code without optimization.

Comment: depends on the compiler

Comment: @Aiias Not necessarily.  Branches can be expensive since they could stall your pipeline if the prediction is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the call is done multiple times, the `if` will become seamless because the branch predictor will become aware of the pattern.

The generated assembly becomes largely irrelevant, because the `jmp` will all but be skipped when reached.

If the compiler supports it, you can even use intrinsics (for example `__builtin_expect`) to provide that extra hint that the condition is most likely true.